# "param is missing or the value is empty: color" error in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, parameters, controller

I followed a tutorial on YouTube involving making a simple model, printing out the results and updating the model with a form and did a find and replace for what I was trying to accomplish ("text files, the tutorial involved images)

Everything worked up until around the time I just wanted an single index page and tried merging all the controller logic into the index.

I'm currently getting an error reading `param is missing or the value is empty: color` on `params.require` in the controller below.

```
class ColorsController < ApplicationController
    before_action :find_color, only: [:destroy]

    def index
        @colors = Color.all.order("created_at DESC")

        @color = Color.new(color_params)
    end

    def destroy
        @color.destroy
    end

    private

    def find_color
        @color = Color.find(params[:id])
    end

    def color_params
        params.require(:color).permit(:file)
    end
end
```

What I take from this is that it's not recognizing the @color instance variable, but I don't know or why I'm supposed to rectify this.

**Model:**

```
class Color < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_attached_file :file
    validates_attachment_content_type :file, :content_type => ["application/xml"]
end
```

**Form:**

```
= simple_form_for @color do |f|
  = f.input :file
  = f.submit
```

Explanation of what I'm doing wrong is much appreciated.

Comment: Why would the index page get a form submission with any parameters? How are you making it submit to the index method?

Comment: The form partial is rendered in the index. Doesn't it work like that?

Comment: No; look at the rendered HTML. Rails uses convention; a form will generate the conventional Rails form submission path for the model. If you want to make your app work in a non-Rails-y way then you'll need to manually specify the controller/method you want it to submit to.

Comment: What's the difference? I made a "new" template and "new" method and accomplished the same thing. Why did it stop working when I moved it into the index?

Comment: Look at the rendered HTML. Rails uses convention; a form will generate the conventional Rails form submission path for the model. Look at the form's action. And if you just hit the index page, there *aren't* any parameters because no form was submitted to it.

Comment: What I took from that was that I need to make the form's action go to the index. Will just specifying that work or do I need to change anything in the controller?

Answer (score 0):

> param is missing or the value is empty: color

You should change your `index` method to below

```
def index
  @colors = Color.all.order("created_at DESC")
  @color = Color.new #notice the change here
end
```

Also, you should define a `create` method like below

```
def create
  @color = Color.new(color_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @color.save
        format.html { redirect_to @color, notice: 'Color was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @color }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @color.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
   end
end
```

Comment: I wouldn't like to create show or new templates, though. I'd like to accomplish everything within the index.

Comment: @JackHasaKeyboard I understood your intention, but you need a create method to create records.

Comment: Alright, I edited the controller and the error went away but submitting the form doesn't appear to do anything. It redirects to the new template without showing the JSON error and the amount of records stays the same. Shouldn't there be something "show" related in the controller?

Comment: @JackHasaKeyboard Yeah. You should also have a `show` method if you want to redirect to show method or if you want to redirect to index page after saving then you need to change the create method.